# How many ports can a 20 pin usb3 header support?

Tags: usb-3

If I have a 20/19 pin header on a motherboard or pci-e expansion card, how many actual usb ports does this support?

I've seen most recommend 2 ports per header.

However, a product like this would seem to support 4 ports with one header: http://www.tendak.com/index.php/Product/show/id/116.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intel had defined that header as providing two USB 3.0 ports. There aren't enough pins for more ports.

http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/technical-specification/usb3-internal-connector-cable-specification.pdf

From page 8 of the spec linked above:

`2.1 Signal Descriptions and Pin Assignments

   […]

   Figure 2-1 illustrates the USB3 ICC pin numbering. Note that the connector include[s] two USB ports.

   [Figure 2-1 shows a 19-pin header connector pinout]

   Users may choose to include more or less USB ports by expanding or reducing the pin and wire counts. This document covers only the base unit with two USB ports.`

That product you linked to apparently has a built-in USB 3.0 hub (or two) to allow it to provide additional ports. The site even calls it a "front panel USB **hub**".

Answer (score 1):

The 20 pin usb 3.0 connector socket passively allows two usb 3.0 female type A sockets two be wired in...

With the use of active "hub" you could split these 2 physical connections into multiple connections... But as with all active adaptations... Latency will be introduced; you'll be introducing a "middle man" (or you know another PCB) between your usb 3.0 devices and your motherboard...

Sticking to the physical limitations of your motherboard and running only 2 x usb 3.0 females type A to every usb 3.0 20 pin female motherboard socket will yield best performance...

Answer (score -1):

The usb 3 header can provide 2 usb2 headers.  Therefore a usb3 header can provide *4* usb2 ports or *2* usb3 ports without a hub.

Comment: no it doesnt.  A usb3 header can provide 2 usb2 header, which then allows 2x2 or 4 usb2 ports.  Where did anyone say that before?  I know it is true, it is a cable only, no hubs and works fine.  MODDYI sells it

Comment: Source for the 2x2 claim? It is true that a normal USB2 header would support 2 ports, but a splitter isn't exactly the kind of "usual" thing you could apply common wisdom to. I do have one myself for instance (it's for USB2 by MZHOU, and not modDIY, but still) and while it can "merge" two physically different cables/sources.. you'd better hope none of them offered/used two ports because only one will work on each end of the Y. Then, I'm not an electrical engineer, but the spec [seems](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/power_delivery_motherboards.pdf) to suggest similar behaviour to USB3.